# How can i do table sort in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I think this is an easy problem, but I am struggling to understand why this error happens

> Unexpected value 'AppModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

I am trying to use **ng-sort** library [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sort/v/0.1.18] in my angular project to make a table sortable,

this is my **app.module.ts**

```
...
import { AppModule as SortModule } from 'ng-sort';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LogInComponent,
    HomeComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SortModule, 
...       
  ],
  providers: [ThemeService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

also, I did it in my **clients-mod.module** because I use lazy loading

```
...
import { AppModule as SortModule } from 'ng-sort';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainClientComponent,
    ClientInfoComponent,
    ClientDetailComponent,
    ClientsAccComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
...

    SortModule

  ]
})
export class ClientsModModule { }
export class AppModule {

}
```

any suggestions to resolve this issue or any other way to be able to sort based on the column that is clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using below method -

```
import * as SortModule from 'ng-sort';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LogInComponent,
    HomeComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SortModule.AppModule, 
...       
  ],
  providers: [ThemeService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

> This is causing issue because appModule is your Main Module's name and you cannot use same name as import.

Comment: Thanks for the support, the same error still happens after I edit my **app.module** and **client-mod-module** also

Comment: This module is wrong by design, You cannot do anything, the way is to import it using alias which I recommend in my answer.

Comment: so, can you advise me how can I be able to sort based on the column that is clicked on. in a simple way